# VBA | Regex | Matching fraction characters (e.g. 1/8, 3/8) in string

Tags: regex, vba, special-characters

I have the following VBA regex code snippet, want to add ⅜ and ⅝ to the pattern but VBA editor does not recognize them (Showing "?" when I copy and paste).

Is there a way I can incorporate them? I imagine using Chr function might help but not sure how to put that in in a regex context.

```
Dim Reg As Object
Set Reg = = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Reg.Pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9¾½]+)"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy with hex representation of these symbols.

If you paste these `¾½` symbols into a [Unicode char converter](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/), you will get `\u00BE\u00BD` in the JavaScript field. Use them instead of the literal symbols.

You'd just use

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9\u00BE\u00BD]+"
```

Note there is no need wrapping the whole pattern with a capturing group.

Another way is to use the values from the Decimal pane inthe `ChrW$(i)` function, but you will need to concat the strings:

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9" & ChrW$(190) & ChrW$(189) & "]+"
```

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! Exactly what I need!  :)